# C drive memory overloading by running swing

Tags: java, php, swing

I'm making a management software in java for a book store. There is a database on my server. I get my database data by php code.which is also in my server.I use the code below to get data by running the php code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpUtility {

    private static HttpURLConnection httpConn;

public static HttpURLConnection sendGetRequest(String requestURL)
        throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(false);

    return httpConn;
}

public static HttpURLConnection sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
        Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);

    httpConn.setDoInput(true);

    StringBuffer requestParams = new StringBuffer();

    if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {

        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);

        Iterator<String> paramIterator = params.keySet().iterator();
        while (paramIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = paramIterator.next();
            String value = params.get(key);
            requestParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            requestParams.append("=").append(
                    URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
            requestParams.append("&");
        }

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                httpConn.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(requestParams.toString());
        writer.flush();
    }

    return httpConn;
}

public static String readSingleLineRespone() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    if (httpConn != null) {
        inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Connection is not established.");
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));

    String response = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();

    return response;
}

public static String[] readMultipleLinesRespone() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    if (httpConn != null) {
        inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Connection is not established.");
    }

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.add(line);
    }
    reader.close();

    return (String[]) response.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public static void disconnect() {
    if (httpConn != null) {
        httpConn.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

Now I'm facing a problem like the image link (don't have enough reputation for the upload)below.There are 3 image link.

[before log in](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgyh5ofdpdvhliq/Screenshot%202014-11-07%2003.16.17.png?dl=0)

[After the log in and before the search query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ex6p8d3mzgipwrk/Screenshot%202014-11-07%2003.16.28.png?dl=0)

Another link is in the comment.
After every request making my C:// drive is loosing 10 MB space and I don't know why(Very noob coder sorry.)
Can anyone help me.

Comment: After the search query-https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojzu8n3lkiq9auf/Screenshot%202014-11-07%2003.16.52.png?dl=0

Comment: What happens when you close the program?

Comment: C:// drive go back to initial space

Comment: Change the `HttpUtility` so that it sends back "pretend" data (comment out all the `HttpURLConnection` related stuff) and see if you still have the same issue.  It could be the OS expanding it's own disk cache...

Comment: it was causing for a recursive function